# Smarty if statements and big numbers

Tags: php, if-statement, smarty

This code

```
{if 10111060108552250999929 == 10111060108552250999924} 
true1 
{/if} 
{if 10111060108552250999929 == 20111060108552250999924} 
true2 
{/if}
```

outputs 'true1' but neither statement is true.

Does Smarty have a maximum size for comparing integers? If so, why does it appear to be a bit "fuzzy"?

Hopefully I've just made a stupid mistake.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Bugger. I'm going to have to compare them as strings, then. Ta.

Comment: No changes. It will still produce you the same output. Since, PHP will automatically convert them into INT, see here http://codepad.org/jLTOBz6z

Comment: Yeah, I figured. I'll have to put a space in or something. Bah, frankly.

Comment: Since I've got no love for Smarty, I also don't know how to force it to compare items as strings. In PHP you can always use `settype()` for typecasting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the problem with PHP's integer type overflow. It varies based on the OS bit (32/64).

Please see:

> If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return a float instead.
>
> http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow

Comment: can you not di if(float(1231112312312...)==float(1231231213...))

Answer (score 0):

Since these numbers are too large for the regular `int` type, Smarty will (as per the [automatic conversion PHP does](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow)) be comparing them as `float`s, resulting in loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider writing a comparsion plugin for smarty usin [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php), therefore big numbers will be handled correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I might be wrong, but your second if statement is always false...as those numbers are not the same..

Comment: Both statements are false, but it evaluates the first one as true.